# How to train (fit) concatenated model in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

Hello this is the model that after some edits I created for classification IMDB movies purpose. It consist of two concatenated models (LSTM and CNN)

```
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
np.random.seed(7)

top_words = 5000
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=top_words)
max_review_length = 5
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_review_length)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_review_length)   


def cnn_lstm_merged():
        embedding_vecor_length = 32
        cnn_model = Sequential()
        cnn_model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))
        cnn_model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
        cnn_model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
        cnn_model.add(Flatten())

        lstm_model = Sequential()
        lstm_model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))
        lstm_model.add(LSTM(64, activation = 'relu', return_sequences=True))
        lstm_model.add(Flatten())

        merge = Concatenate([lstm_model, cnn_model])
        hidden = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')

        conc_model = Sequential()
        conc_model.add(merge)
        conc_model.add(hidden)

        conc_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        history = conc_model.fit([X_train, X_train], [y_train, y_train], np.reshape([y_train, y_train],(25000,2)),epochs=3, batch_size=(64,64))
        return history
```

X_train shape is (25000, 5)
y_train shape is (25000,)
I don't know how to train this model because there are problems.
The error is:

```
File "/home/pythonist/Desktop/EnsemblingLSTM_CONV/train.py", line 79, in <module>
    cnn_lstm_model = cnn_lstm_merged()
  File "/home/pythonist/Desktop/EnsemblingLSTM_CONV/train.py", line 69, in cnn_lstm_merged
    history = conc_model.fit([X_train, X_train], [y_train, y_train], np.reshape([y_train, y_train],(25000,2)),epochs=3, batch_size=(64,64))
TypeError: fit() got multiple values for argument 'batch_size'
```

Even after I changed batch_size = (64, 64) to batch_size = 64 is still gives me an error. And I'm not sure if I reshaped y_train properly.
How to train and predict an output data in this concatenated model ?  Thank you

Comment: can you post the other error as well which you get after `batch_size = 64`

Comment: It has exactly the same error after changing to batch_size = 64: TypeError: fit() got multiple values for argument 'batch_size'
[Finished in 4.8s with exit code 1]